# Best way to compare multi-dimension hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I want to write a script that can compare two multi-dimension hash to see whether they match or not. This two hash has same value of key, the comparison will done in a pair mean starting with `$j=0` first compare `$line[0] $line[1]` then follow by `$line[2] $line[3]`

```
$hash{"key"}{$key}{"$row $col"}= "$line[$j] $line[$j+1]";
$hash1{"key"}{$key1}{"$row1 $col1"}="$line1[$j] $line1[$j+1]";
```

my $line and $line1 is take from a huge file and will process the huge file line by line. For example:

```
@line = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 #fst line from file1
@line1 = 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 #fst line from file2
```

when `$key` and `$key1` match the scripts will continue to compare the `$row $col` then lastly compare `$line[$j] $line[$j+1]`. I am trying to use one of the module `Test::More` that mention at previous similar question but it can only compare the 1st not matching and the output is in default format.

```
not ok 1 - data structures should be the same
#   Failed test 'data structures should be the same'
#   at hash_check1.pl line 80.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{key}{100}{2 3} = '62 19'
#     $expected->{key}{100}{2 3} = '12 24'
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
```

Any best way to compare this type of multi-dimension hash?

8/22 Edited

If `Test::More` module is able to compare all the `$key` match for two hash i can take that as well but if i can output the matching and non matching in my own prefer format will be great. For example i would like to output like

```
$key at $row $col no match with value $line[$j] $line[$j+1] ( expected value $line1[$j] $line1[$j+1] )
```

8/22 Edited

Below is part of my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

open ( FILE1 , '<', "file.txt" ) or die $!;
open ( FILE2 , '<' , "file1.txt" ) or die $!;

chomp (my @file1 = <FILE1>);
chomp (my @file2 = <FILE2>);
my %hash=();
my %hash1=();

for ( $i =0 ; $i<=511 ; $i++ ) {
    my @line = split(" ",$file1[$i]);
    my @line1 = split(" ",$file2[$i]);
    my $key = ($i+1)*10;
    my $key1 = ($i+2)*10;

    for ( $j=0; $j<=15 ; $j+=2){
          my $col = hex($j);
          my $col1 = hex($j+1);
          $hash{"key"}{$key}{"$row $col1"}= "$line[$j] $line[$j+1]";
          $hash1{"key"}{$key1}{"$row1 $col1"}= "$line1[$j] $line1[$j+1]";
    }
}

##############comparison part start here###################
is_deeply(\%hash, \%hash1, 'data structures should be the same'); #can only print one mismatch

################Any better way?###########
```

Comment: You mean you want to compare, but without using the test module? You're asking how to write the code yourself which is similar to what the test is using? If so, looking inside the source of `Test::More` could give you the answers you need. You can brows the source here: https://metacpan.org/source/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302086/lib/Test/More.pm

Comment: Hi @piojo, i can use the test module but i am not sure how to compare all the `$key` for the hash and is it a possible way to change the output pattern for this `Test::More` module?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you're really asking--do you want a deep comparison, or are you trying to get a deep comparison that ignores a certain level of keys?

Comment: Hi @piojo, the final objective is to compare the `$line[$j] $line1[$j+1]` but this only be done when all the key in front are match. The comparison result using `Test::More` is good enough but i would like to compare all the `$key` and `$key1` match and not only one like what i show above. And if i can output the matching result by my own format will be great. For example i would like to display like `$key at $row $col no match with value $line[$j] $line[$j+1] ( expected value $line1[$j] $line1[$j+1]`

Comment: @piojo, thanks for the advise, i has make some modification in my question for better understanding

Comment: @Tim Do you want to fix the index `$j` in `@line` and `@line1`? Or do you want the comparison to be done for the whole arrays, starting with `$j = 0` and comparing first `"$line[0] $line[1]"` with `"$line1[0] $line1[1]"`, then comparing `"$line[1] $line[2]"` with `"$line1[1] $line1[2]"`, and so on?

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland, the comparison will done in pair starting from `$j = 0` and comparing first `$line[0] $line[1]` and next `$line[2] $line[3]`. I have edit my question. Thanks

Comment: The test will be easiest if it's a recursive function, which also keeps track of how deep it has searched--it has to remember the "path" (all the keys) so it can list that in the error message. Just compare the key list, then recurse with a comparison on each key. The base case will be comparing plain values (not containers). There's no simple way to get around writing the code. It would be easier if you just wanted a true/false answer, though.

Comment: I am still not sure about what you are trying to do. Let's say `@line = (0, 1, 2, 3)` and `@line1 = (0, 1, 4, 5)`. Then suppose `$key eq $key1` and `"$row $col" eq "$row1 $col1"`. Further assume `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "0 1"` and `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "0 1"`. Then, now what is the purpose of introducing the `@line`, `@line1` and  `$j` variables?  What output would you expect in this case? Something like `"$key at $row $col no match with value 2 3 ( expected value 4 5 )"`? But this does not make sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, i has modified my question for better understanding. Basically my $line and $line1 is the line from a huge file for example my `@line=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) and @line1=(1 2 3 3 5 6 7 7)` when `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "1 2"` it will match with `%hash1` but when come to second part when `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "3 4"` it will not match with `%hash1 which = 3 3` then print the ouput `$key at $row $col no match with value 2 3 ( expected value 3 3 )"`. The purpose to introduce `$j` is because the value compare is come in pairs

Comment: @Tim You say *"..when `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "1 2"`"*, then later you say *"..when `$hash{key}{$key}{"$row $col"} eq "3 4"`"*. Does this this mean that `%hash` changes value somehow during the comparison operation? I thought that `%hash` and `%hash1` were fixed, and you wanted to compare them from that point of view.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, i will store all the value inside `%hash` and `%hash1`. When all the value from the file stored. i will make the comparison between `%hash` and `%hash1`. The value will not change during comparison process.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I give up. Please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HåkonHægland, i add the code i store the thing inside the hash but i am not sure how to continue for the comparison part. Hope you can understand this.

Comment: You should check out chapter 1 of  Higher Order Perl.  MJD does a great job of explaining how to use recursion to walk a data structure.  He also demonstrates how you can use callback functions to compose complex behaviors (such as customized reporting).   https://hop.perl.plover.com/book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that will compare nested hashes with string values:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
my %hash1;

$hash{"key"}{A}{"2 3"}= "1 2";
$hash1{"key"}{A}{"2 3"}="2 3";
$hash{"key"}{B}{"2 3"}= "1 2";
$hash1{"key"}{C}{"2 3"}="2 3";

compare(\%hash, \%hash1);

sub compare {
    return _compare( @_, "" );
}

sub get_key_str { return $_[0] . '{' . $_[1] . '}' }

sub _process_key {
    my ( $h1, $h2, $info, $key, $str1, $str2 ) = @_;

    if ( exists $h2->{$key} ) {
        my $val1 = $h1->{$key};
        my $val2 = $h2->{$key};
        if ( ref $val1 eq "HASH" and ref $val2 eq "HASH" ) {
            _compare( $val1, $val2, get_key_str( $info, $key ) );
        }
        else {
            die "Expected string value" if ref $val1 or ref $val2;
            if ( $val1 ne $val2 ) {
                say "Value '$val1' in $str1 hash for key " . get_key_str( $info, $key )
                  . " does not match value '$val2' in $str2 hash";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        my $cur_key = get_key_str( $info, $key );
        say "Got key $cur_key in $str1 hash, but missing in $str2 hash"; 
    }
}


sub _compare {
    my ( $h1, $h2, $info ) = @_;

    my %processed_keys;
    for (keys %$h1) {
        _process_key( $h1, $h2, $info, $_, "first", "second" );
        $processed_keys{$_}++;
    }
    for (keys %$h2) {
        next if exists $processed_keys{$_};
        _process_key( $h2, $h1, $info, $_, "second", "first" );
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Got key {key}{B} in first hash, but missing in second hash
Value '1 2' in first hash for key {key}{A}{2 3} does not match value '2 3' in second hash
Got key {key}{C} in second hash, but missing in first hash
```

Comment: Hi @Hakon, i try to modified your code to print the thing inside output file but it does not work. I try to change `say` to `print FILE` but the file print out is empty. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @Tim Hi. It difficult for me to tell why its not printing without seeing more of your code. You could try send me the code, and I will have a look at it.

Comment: Hi @Hakon, can i edit your answer by adding the line i add in command?I dont know how to send you my code